# How can I split a big XML file into smallers with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, split

I have XML file with over 300 000 entries which my script has to parse each day..

The xml is with structure as :

```
<root>
     <item>
        <proper1></proper1>
        <proper2></proper2>
    </item>
</root>
```

I need to split the big XML file into smaller files so my PHP can run them, currently it cant proccess it because it uses too much memory.
Can any one help me with that ?

Comment: It is certainly easy to split a file, but you would need to provide more details, like how you wanted it to be split. Also if you are loading the whole thing into memory each time, it makes no difference if it is 1 file or 100 files, it is going to take the same memory when it is finished. Do you need to read the whole thing and store it?

Comment: My script which parses the file have DB queries and image proccesses so I think that it will be better if I prepare the xml to have some limit of entries 20 000 - 30 000 per file.

So this split should split the entries with Max limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please take a look at this article [PHP XML Parsing](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xmlphp2/index.html)

1. SAX parsing
2. XML Reader [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php) Pull Parser

will be the best suited for this job

Read the above article try some code with it you will definitely get the answer for this

Comment: I know those thing, but in the parser when a file is parsed it runs db queries and image proccesses which takes a huge memory and time for proccess this why I need this big file splitted before the parser gets it.

Comment: I had suspected as much, yet maxjackie's advice (+1) is good: to be able to split the file efficiently you either make fast assumptions (as I did), or else employ the much more clever and almost as fast XML Parser.

Answer (score 12):

Much would depend on your XML file structure.

For example, you could do something like this (assuming the structure is the one you posted, carriage returns included, otherwise things get more complicated):

**Line-chopping version: blazing fast slicing a large XML file if formatted "just right"**
*while crashing and burning if the file is not formatted just exactly like so*

```
$fp = fopen(XMLFILE, 'r');
$decl = fgets($fp, 1024);  // Drop the XML declaration '<?xml...?>'
$root = fgets($fp, 1024);  // Drop the root declaration
$n = 1;
while(!feof($fp)) {
    $tag = fgets($fp, 1024);
    if ('<item>' === $tag) {
        isset($gp) || trigger_error('Unexpected state');
        $gp = fopen("chunk{$n}.xml", 'w'); $n++;
        // Write the header of the file we saved from before
        fwrite($gp, $decl);
        fwrite($gp, $root);
    } else if ('</item>' === $tag) {
        fwrite($gp, $tag);
        fwrite($gp, '</root>');
        fclose($gp); unset($gp);
        continue;
    }
    if (!isset($gp)) {
        if ('</root>' === $tag /* EOF */) {
            break;
        } else {
            trigger_error('Unexpected state 2');
        }
    }
    fwrite($gp, $tag);
}
fclose($fp);
isset($gp) || trigger_error('Unexpected state 3');
```

This has the major benefit of allowing you to 'recycle' your XML parsing script (indeed, you could call the XML parsing script as soon as you close $gp, or even better, not write to any file at all but enqueue fwrites on a buffer, and call the script with that buffer).

Another advantage is to be able to 'outsource' the files among different subservers, for example is XML processing is long due to DNS resolutions, DB calls, HTTP/SOAP calls, need for feedback and so on. In that case you could save the file in different subdirectories based on ($n % NUM_CLIENTS), and every client could fetch one file at a time, process and delete it and go on.

Yet, the best way to proceed would be instead to rewrite your script in order not to load the XML in memory but parse it a little at a time, using the XML Parser support.

A compromise is to use XML Parser to slice the XML file and feed it to your existing script, "as is".

**XMLparse version: efficiently slicing and dicing a large XML file**
*without worrying about how the XML is actually put together*

The xmlparse functions work through callbacks, i.e. you feed your data to an entry point (xml_parse) which then analyzes the data, splits it, routes the various chunks to the appropriate subfunctions which you define. xml_parse will deal with encoding and whitespace, thereby freeing you from the need of coping with same, which is one of the greatest drawbacks in the above code. The xmlparse core itself does not keep data, so we can achieve a constant-memory implementation even for gigabyte (or terabyte) files.

So let us see how to rewrite the code for XMLParser, and chunk the big file by splitting a certain number of repetitions of a given tag.

I.e., input file:

```
 <root><item>(STUFF OF ITEM1)</item><item>(STUFF OF ITEM2)/item>....ITEM1234...</root>
```

output files:

```
 FILE1: <root><item>(1)</item><item>(2)</item>...(5)</root>
 FILE2: <root><item>(6)</item><item>(7)</item>...(10)</root>
 ...
```

We do this by writing a XMLparser that will extract each "chunk" of N (here N=5) items and feed it to a chunk processor, which upon receiving ... will wrap it between  tags, add a XML header, and thus produce a file with the same syntax of the original big file, but with only five items.

To save in separate files, we keep track of chunk number.

```
    function processChunk($lastChunk = false) {
         GLOBAL $CHUNKS, $PAYLOAD, $ITEMCOUNT;
         if ('' == $PAYLOAD) {
             return;
         }
         $xp = fopen($file = "output-$CHUNKS.xml", "w");
         fwrite($xp, '<?xml version="1.0"?>'."\n");
             fwrite($xp, "<root>");
                 fwrite($xp, $PAYLOAD);
             $lastChunk || fwrite($xp, "</root>");
         fclose($xp);
         print "Written {$file}\n";
         $CHUNKS++;
         $PAYLOAD    = '';
         $ITEMCOUNT  = 0;
    }
```

The xmlparse functions require callbacks: one that receives tag OPENING, one tag CLOSING, one gets the content and another gets the whatever. We're not interesting in the whatever, so we only fill the first three handlers.

```
    function startElement($xml, $tag, $attrs = array()) {
        GLOBAL $PAYLOAD, $CHUNKS, $ITEMCOUNT, $CHUNKON;
        if (!($CHUNKS||$ITEMCOUNT)) {
            if ($CHUNKON == strtolower($tag)) {
                $PAYLOAD = '';
            }
        }
        $PAYLOAD .= "<{$tag}";
        foreach($attrs as $k => $v) {
            $PAYLOAD .= " {$k}=\"" .addslashes($v).'"';
        }
        $PAYLOAD .= '>';
    }

    function endElement($xml, $tag) {
        GLOBAL $CHUNKON, $ITEMCOUNT, $ITEMLIMIT;
        dataHandler(null, "</{$tag}>");
        if ($CHUNKON == strtolower($tag)) {
             if (++$ITEMCOUNT >= $ITEMLIMIT) {
                 processChunk();
             }
        }
    }

    function dataHandler($xml, $data) {
        GLOBAL $PAYLOAD;
        $PAYLOAD .= $data;
    }

    function defaultHandler($xml, $data) {
        // a.k.a. Wild Text Fallback Handler, or WTFHandler for short.
    }
```

The createXMLParser function is standalone for clarity

```
    function createXMLParser($CHARSET, $bareXML = false) {
            $CURRXML = xml_parser_create($CHARSET);
            xml_parser_set_option( $CURRXML, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, false);
            xml_parser_set_option( $CURRXML, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, $CHARSET);
            xml_set_element_handler($CURRXML, 'startElement', 'endElement');
            xml_set_character_data_handler($CURRXML, 'dataHandler');
            xml_set_default_handler($CURRXML, 'defaultHandler');
            if ($bareXML) {
                xml_parse($CURRXML, '<?xml version="1.0"?>', 0);
            }
            return $CURRXML;
    }
```

Finally the feeding loop, which opens Mr. Big File and sends it to the grinder.

```
    function chunkXMLBigFile($file, $tag = 'item', $howmany = 5) {
         GLOBAL $CHUNKON, $CHUNKS, $ITEMLIMIT;

         // Every chunk only holds $ITEMLIMIT "$CHUNKON" elements at most.
         $CHUNKON   = $tag;
         $ITEMLIMIT = $howmany;

         $xml = createXMLParser('UTF-8', false);

         $fp = fopen($file, 'r');
         $CHUNKS  = 0;
         while(!feof($fp)) {
              $chunk = fgets($fp, 10240);
              xml_parse($xml, $chunk, feof($fp));
         }
         xml_parser_free($xml);

         // Now, it is possible that one last chunk is still queued for processing.
         processChunk(true);
    }
```

Then we call the machine: "Split test.xml into pieces of 5 instances of the item tag"

```
    ChunkXMLBigFile('test.xml', 'item', 5);
```

This implementation runs about five times as slow as the stupid chunker at the beginning, but can deal with tags in the same line, and can be even expanded to validate the XML.

Comment: Correction; not so perect .. I have an XML file with aroun 38'000 items. for some reason your script only dumps 30'000. Any idea ? I think it's missing 1-2 chunks.

Comment: I'd have to take a long hard look at the XML to understand why. You can add debug code to the parser - which one are you using? - to check what's happening.

Comment: Ok, please check the file here : http://www.4shared.com/archive/OGceWv6-/axml.html

Comment: You are amazing, this helped me no end! One thing that will hopefully help others: I had all kinds of xml import errors after processing, solved by two minor mods to your code. One needs to wrap using htmlentities in line 28, like so:

`$PAYLOAD .= " $k=".'"'.htmlentities(addslashes($v)).'"';`

and in line 50, like so:

`$PAYLOAD .= htmlentities($data);`

Thanks again for this!

Comment: ok, I spoke too soon. This ALMOST works perfectly, but seems to leave off the last (uneven) chunk and I can't figure out in the code where to make it account for that. For example, I have a file that has 29092 items, split so that there are 400 per file, but I end up with only 72 files which account for only 28800 of the 29092. The last bit of (less than 400) 292 is nowhere to be found. Any ideas?

Comment: :( now I am back to getting xml import errors. If I leave my htmlentities in the code, it fails because now some of the tags come across as &gt; and if I take it out, I get other xml input errors:

`This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML error: XML_ERR_NAME_REQUIRED at line 8, column 609`

I wasn't getting these with the previous code and my mods...

Comment: ok, I have it working again, I had to revert function endElement to previous version of the code.

Comment: sigh. almost. Last file is writing the closing xml twice. No other file does this, just the last one. (ie </channel></rss></channel></rss> at end of file)

Comment: I'll look into it with more calm tonight :-)

Comment: Worked great thx. Just the last closing tag appears twice. Could fix it with: !$ITEMCOUNT === 0 ? fwrite($xp, '</root>') : null;

Comment: @HonsaStunna This happens in the processing of the last chunk (which also contains a closing `</root>`). So I added a parameter to processChunk to let it know when it's going to handle the last chunk of a file.