# PHP split big XML file into smallers?

Tags: php, xml

hy, I hope you can help me!
I have to split a huge file in smaller to put the data into db.
I read a lot of post and I find a really good one this is the url:

[How can I split a big XML file into smallers with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374908/how-can-i-split-a-big-xml-file-into-smallers-with-php)

but I have some problem with it:
1. I have to read a xml with 400.000 record and the script stops at 170.000 and I really don't know how, is there some change I have to do?
2. is it possible to put data in  ?
3. I have to read a huge file and any browser crash. do you know some software where I can read data from url for mac in a simple way?

really thanks!

MORE INFORMATION ABOUT XML FILE:

I copy and past the xml format; instead of three dots there are informations.

```
<?XML version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8” ?> 

<vortigo> 

<annuncio> 

<id_annuncio> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </id_annuncio> 
<link> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </link> 
<titolo> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </titolo> 
<tipo_contratto> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </tipo_contratto> 
<tipologia> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </tipologia> 
<descrizione> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </descrizione> 

<classe_energetica> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </classe_energetica>
<indice_energetica> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </indice_energetica>
<numero_stanze> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </numero_stanze>
<numero_bagni> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </numero_bagni>
<superficie> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </superficie>
<stato_immobile> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </stato_immobile>
<prezzo> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </prezzo> 
<prezzo_giorno> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </prezzo_giorno>
<prezzo_settimana> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </prezzo_settimana>
<prezzo_scontato> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </prezzo_scontato>

<comune> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </comune> 
<nazione> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </nazione> 
<regione> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </regione> 
<provincia> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </provincia> 
<indirizzo> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </indirizzo> 
<cap> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </cap>
<zona> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </zona>
<longitudine> <![CDATA [ . . . ]]> </longitudine>
<latitudine> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </latitudine>
<data_aggiornamento> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </data_aggiornamento> 
<immagini>

<immagine>
<immagine_url> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </immagine_url>
<immagine_titolo> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </immagine_titolo>
</immagine>

<immagine>
<immagine_url> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </immagine_url>
<immagine_titolo> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </immagine_titolo>
</immagine>

...
</immagini> 

<tipo_venditore> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </tipo_venditore>
<agenzia_nome> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </agenzia_nome> 
<agenzia_comune> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </agenzia_comune> 
<agenzia_email> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </agenzia_email> 
<agenzia_url> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </agenzia_url> 

<piscina> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </piscina> 
<giardino> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </giardino> 
<condizionatore> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </condizionatore> 
<riscaldamento> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </riscaldamento> 
<balcone> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </balcone> 
<terrazzo> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </terrazzo> 
<ascensore> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </ascensore> 
<cucina> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </cucina> 
<arredato> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </arredato> 
<parcheggio> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </parcheggio> 

<portale> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </portale> 
<tipo_portale> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </tipo_portale> 
<logo_portale> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </logo_portale> 

</vortigo>
```

information is entered into a database with all the columns for each data.
Thnks in advance!!!!

Comment: Try setting a bigger value for `max_execution_time`. For example `max_execution_time(120);` http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: hy, i did it in the php file. i put set_time_limit(900);
ini_set('memory_limit', '20000M'); but not change.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question. Also large XML files in case you hit some memory limit, consider to use XMLReader, there are also iterators for it: [XMLReaderIterator](https://github.com/hakre/XMLReaderIterator)

Comment: Humm, then are you sure that your XML is valid?

Comment: your xml is not valid. you are missing a closing `<annuncio> `-Element

Comment: Please stop rolling back your post to remove what was needed to re-open it.

Answer (score 2):

What code are your using to parse the XML? As the question you reffer to was answered you should not use the easy `SimpleXML` as it is very slow and memory intensive. 
Here is a simple example for the XMLReader-Class that works really efficient with larger files because it streams them and not reads in the file as a whole:

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open('file.xml');

while ($xml->read()) {
    // elements only. skipp element end-tags and cdata etc
    if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {

          // process the Elements e.g. in a switch statement:
          switch ($xml->name) {
                //...
          }
    }
}
```

Your can apply changes for example in the `switch`-Statement as you can access the content via the `$xml->readOuterXML()` function. If you want an easier access to the content you might want to parse specific parts with the `SimpleXMLElement` again:

```
 $elem = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXML());
```

Don't forget to `unset` the `$elem` after you are done, to free memory for upcoming entries. I use the exact same method and can parse 10k entries in 2s with a decent memory usage.

To your last question: You maybe want to split the content into subparts. Or you make the file downloadable so the user can open it as a whole on his computer. Unfortunatly HTTP is not the fastest protocoll and is also not designed for massive file sizes.

Edit: I updated my [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/ferdynator/644a0cfedea3c9072546) to match your example-data. It might take some more configuration e.g. because your `<immagini>` requires some nested loops. But it will give you a good idea about how to solve this issue.

Comment: hy, I'm using the script that starts :"function processChunk($xmlstring)
    {
         GLOBAL $CHUNKS;
         $xp = fopen($file = "output-$CHUNKS.xml", "w");
         fwrite($xp, '<?xml version="1.0"?>'."\n");
             fwrite($xp, "<root>");
                 fwrite($xp, $xmlstring);
             fwrite($xp, "</root>");
         fclose($xp);
         print "Written $file\n";
         $CHUNKS++;
    } and so on.. what i want is to divide the xml file in smaller file to insert data in the database

Comment: in what kind of format do you want the xml in the database? as a string or mapped to a certain table?

Comment: i would like it in a table with multiple records!

Comment: that can be done with my code. add a `case` for every element that matches a table and then insert the values into your database. I created an example in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ferdynator/644a0cfedea3c9072546)

Comment: really thank for your example, i'll try. my xml file is like <root>
<Categories>
<id>..</id>
<name>..</name> <state>..</state>
</Categories>
</root> i can use it as well? thanks

Comment: sure. Check out the [SimpleXML-Dokumentation](http://de3.php.net/manual/de/class.simplexmlelement.php) it should give you a clue about how to go from here. Glad I could help :)

Comment: hy, i'm reading the url you linked (simplexml-documentation) but i can not see the light. your script it's really good, to charge all the date i have to add data in the swich case? i'm getting crazy...

Comment: you need to supply some more information about the structure of your xml-Element if you want me to help you more. Plase add it to your question

Comment: i copy and past the xml format; instead of three dots there are informations. <?XML version=“1.0” encoding=“UTF-8” ?> 

<vortigo> 

<annuncio> 

<id_annuncio> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </id_annuncio> obbligatorio
<link> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </link> 
<titolo> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </titolo> 




<immagini>

<immagine>
<immagine_url> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </immagine_url>
<immagine_titolo> <![CDATA[ . . . ]]> </immagine_titolo>
</immagine>




</immagini> 



</vortigo>
i really thanks you for your helps!

Comment: please [edit your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work) accordingly and format the code corretcly so it is easier to review. ty :)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you script crashes by one of following reasons:
1) Memory/time limit for PHP script. It can be setted in your php.ini file
2) Incorrect values in you XML, what can't be parsed by parser script you use.

Comment: hy if there is some incorrect value in the xml is it possible to correct it or jump and go on? thanks.

Comment: It's depends from you parser settings and sensitivity to errors

Comment: how can i set parser error in the script to show the problems?

Comment: Also, it's good idea to normalize target XML before use. Try to google following phrase: php fix xml errors

Comment: what do you mean for "normalize target xml"? do you have some example to show?

Comment: Errors logging also differs from parser to parser. Typically to you can help this native PHP things:

error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set('display_errors',1);

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.normalize.php