# How to save whole XML node at once?

Tags: php, xml

I have one XML file with 2455 items in it and I want to break it down into few seperate files each containing only 100 items.

```
<style_list>
 <style>
  <product_id>1</product_id>
  <product_name>Item 1</product_name>
  <product_ean>1111</product_ean>
 </style>
 <style>
  <product_id>1</product_id>
  <product_name>Item 2</product_name>
  <product_ean>2222</product_ean>
 </style>
```

And so on, 2455 times. So I would like to grab whole  part and copy it into seperate file.

```
if (file_exists('items.xml')) {
   $xml = simplexml_load_file('items.xml');

   foreach($xml->style as $item)
     {file_put_contents("items2.xml", $item , FILE_APPEND);
   }
```

This is how I imagined it would work, but it doesn't write anything into file. I assume that I could do it in a "$item->product_id" and write every attribute separately, but each item has like 30 attributes.

Comment: Have a look at [how-can-i-split-a-big-xml-file-into-smallers-with-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374908/how-can-i-split-a-big-xml-file-into-smallers-with-php)

Answer (score -2):

Use XSLT 2.0+

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="/*/style" group-adjacent="position() idiv 100">
    <xsl:result-document href="items{position()}.xml">
      <style_list>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </style_list>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```